# Lipschitz constant for two variables function

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Let $f(x,y)=y^{\frac{2}{3}}$. I want to show that functions is Lipschitz function w.r.t $y$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ or not.

Given definition of function that satisfy Lipschitz conditions w.r.t to $y$, i.e.

> A function $f(x,y)$ defined on a (open or closed) domain $D$ is said to satisfy Lipschitz conditions with respect to $y$ for the constant $K>0$ if for every $x, y_1,y_2$ such that $(x,y_1),(x,y_2)$ are in $D$
> $$|f(x,y_1)-f(x,y_2)|≤K|y_1-y_2|$$

I tried to do by using that definition. This is my attempt:
$|f(x,y_1)-f(x,y_2)|=|y_1^{2/3}-y_2^{2/3}|≤K|y_1-y_2|$

Then I don't know how what must I do next.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Put $y_2=0$ and take $y_1$ near $0$.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Okay, I have put $y_2=0$ and take $y_1$ near $0$. Then I conclude that $f(x,y)=y^{\frac{2}{3}}$ is not satisfy Lipschitz condition, is it right?

Comment: Yes, that is right.